# Getting FBI challenge coins from FBI field offices / resident agencies?

Tags: usa, souvenirs, government-buildings

I was thinking a cool souvenir for US cities would be to get an FBI Challenge Coin whenever I'm in a city with an FBI Field Office or Resident Agency. Unfortunately, it is not clear to me how this might be done.

I got a challenge coin from the Austin Resident Agency from a friend who attended an [FBI Citizens Academy](https://www.fbi.gov/contact-us/field-offices/sanantonio/community-outreach-1) and, according to him, he was able to get me one because, during one of the classes, they were selling FBI paraphernalia, some of which included challenge coins. That's not something I'm going to be able to do while on vacation. Honestly, it's not even clear to me how I'd get one from my own hometown, which has a Resident Agency, let alone from another city.

I'm sure I could buy the challenge coins on eBay but imho that cheapens the experience. I'd rather my souvenirs have a story behind them. Like "I went there and I got this" instead of "I went on eBay and I got this".

Comment: As I understand the custom, challenge coins aren't usually generally available: they're presented as some sort of recognition or honor. You could just call up the appropriate FBI office and ask, but I suspect you're usually not receiving one unless you know someone.

Comment: If you want a challenge, follow *World of Warcraft* rules for the use of flight points (airports).  You can only fly to a place after you have journeyed there via other means, and introduced yourself to the flight master (airport manager). No fair using transfers; if you live in LA and have traveled by land to JFK, you can fly JFK-LAX but you can't add Atlanta just because you changed planes there.

Comment: VTC: what exactly is the question (and is it a travel related other than having to go to multiple offices or events)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about FBI memorabilia and the travel involved is purely incidental.